# Not getting whole blockchain dataset

Tags: google-bigquery

When i I run in BigQuery

`SELECT count(block_id)
from "bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain.blocks"`

I am only getting 912. But the dataset "bigquery-public-data:bitcoin_blockchain" should contain the whole blockchain. Why can't I get access to the whole dataset? I have tried it in both the WebUI and Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain dataset has two tables:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT table_id, row_count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain.__TABLES__`
```

Take a look at respective row counts

```
Row table_id        row_count    
1   blocks          912  
2   transactions    1085526
```

> Update:

This seems to be fixed now

```
Row table_id        row_count    
1   blocks          528,854  
2   transactions    323,974,319
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have looked at the row counts. And number the number of row count in the blocks table should be far more than 912 at this time. There are current 528486 number of blocks in the blockchain.

Comment: so, you are getting all that are available in the public dataset. I think this exactly answers your question - at least the way I understood it :o) so it might should - but looks like it does not contain all

Comment: According to Google's blog "https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2018/02/bitcoin-in-bigquery-blockchain-analytics-on-public-data". The whole blockchain should be available in the dataset. "The Bitcoin blockchain data are now available for exploration with BigQuery. All historical data are in the bigquery-public-data:bitcoin_blockchain dataset, which updates every 10 minutes."

Comment: I have also looked at the timestamps in the transactions table, and it contains transactions for approximately 10 days. Do you know how I can get access to the whole blockchain?

Comment: as you can see  - this is clearly an overstatement - you should submit issue to   https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0